# Is two-finger non-homerow touch-typing for programming acceptable?

Tags: typing, wpm

I'm currently typing about 90 wpm (from http://speedtest.10-fast-fingers.com/ 90 correct 0 missed) using two fingers and the occasional ring or index.  This probably grew from learning to type at an early age, before home-row was presented to me.

Is this acceptable?  Do people religiously endorse home-row even with low-mistake poking without looking at the keyboard?

Comment: Do all 90 words compile?

Comment: You should post a video on YouTube. I would like to see what 90 WPM 2-finger typing looks like.

Comment: Haha thanks.  I'll bust out my phone soon  XD

Comment: Seriously, I would really love to see this as well.  You're really typing 90wpm without all your fingers?

Comment: Here is me typing in an awkward position.  I hope this cell phone video is as good quality as you guys are expecting.  No HD here!  It's weird typing off the top of my head, but it will do.  I bet this is about 80 WPM, cause I have complete sentances and am typing as I think.  I bet the phone's 15 second timer is up, so ya, goodnight.  URL under here.  

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRCkrP6MkgQ
Seems slower than it is..

Comment: The text in the above comment is what I was typing.  Probably should have typed something predone, and used a real camera.  Aw well.  Hope you guys can get a laugh  XD.

Comment: "This video has been removed by the user" - bummer!  I just came across this Q and also wanted to see.

Comment: Sorry, seemed like a dead end and it was annoying me on youtube  XD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as your typing is fast and accurate, no one has a right to judge...

Comment: Touche.  Simple effective answer.

Answer (score 2):

90 wpm is a good typing speed. As long as you're being as efficient as possible, go for it!

The only reason you may want to learn home-row typing is so that you can know how fast you are using that method. If you're doing 90 by poking, you'd probably be a speed demon with home-row!

Comment: Well, I've honestly been doing touch typing since third grade.  I used to IM a lot, our little town loved AIM.  My hands like blur/skim fractions of an inch over the keys.  Massive muscle memory.

I'd hate to re-learn.  Also, my hands never hurt.  Wayyyy too much time on the computer.

And this test was taken on my laptop.  I've hit 130 before.  It's just...in this field some people are SO RELIGIOUS about many things beyond reason.

Comment: I totally agree with you. My only point is that if you don't know how fast you are with home-row typing, it wouldn't hurt to try. But 90 WPM is a perfectly adequate speed for programming.

Answer (score 2):

90WPM is a good typing speed. In fact people can easily learn and improve there typing speed with the help of many touch typing software in the market. These software are easily available in the market and easy to learn as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you are typing 90 wpm with two fingers then by all means don't stop in my opinion.  I learned via the home-row style and only average around 30 - 50 wpm. :)

I actually got a D in my typing class (still typewriter) and I remember telling my teacher, I'm never going to use this....

Ah, famous last words of a youngen... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are people who are religious about it.  But if you can type 90 wpm with two fingers, who cares what other people think?  Your two fingers are faster than my 10.

Here's someone who is religious about it.  Makes for amusing reading:
http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/09/programmings-dirtiest-little-secret.html

I second Robert Cartaino's suggestion about putting a video on youtube.  I want to see this!  No video editing tricks allowed.

Comment: Ya, I read dirtiest little secret almost twice.  Cool article.

Answer (score 1):

Speed and accuracy is more important than how many fingers you type with. Perhaps more important though is how much concentration your typing method requires. This is an area where touch typing has an advantage.

Programmers that don't need to stop and look at their keyboard have a higher probability of putting their ideas into code quickly and efficiently. It is argued that non-touch typists may be more prone to taking shortcuts that sacrifice code quality.

Jeff Atwood has a nice [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001188.html) on this subject which contains a reference to a much longer rant on [Stevey's Blog](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/09/programmings-dirtiest-little-secret.html).

Comment: Hehe, I don't think when I type.  That's like a doctor who has no feeling in his hands.  Wrong profession, son  XD

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that people who know how to touch type tend to write more documentation in their code - just because it's easy. That's why I would check the typing speed of programmers when hiring, and 10 finger typists would have some bonus.

By the way: learning home-row typing is probably much easier for you than you think. Just understand the basic principle and remind yourself periodically how it should be done and how to place your hands on the keyboard, and you will be typing faster and more conveniently in a couple of weeks. There is no need to take a course or something.

Answer (score 1):

Who in hell would care how you use a keyboard?

Our code is our art, somebody caring how you typed it is like someone refusing to buy art because of how an artist holds the pencil.

So, this question could not be more irrelevant. Voting to close.

Comment: When I first saw this answer in the late-answer queue (which you'll have access to in 552 reputation), I thought it was harsh. Then I read the question, which just seemed like idle boasting, and I'm tempted instead to vote it up. (while also voting to delete the now-closed question!)

Answer (score 0):

In middle school I typed blazingly fast using the first two fingers of each hand and both thumbs. I was made to take a touch-typing class (on horrible IBM Selectrics), forgot the system I'd invented, and have never been able to recover the speed I had when I was eleven. If the shoe fits, then by all means wear it.

Comment: I suspect at least *some* of that speed drop is due to the fact that you're not eleven anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

My concern wouldn't be about whether your typing style is acceptable, but whether it's safe.  Although I don't have any evidence that this is the case, it's possible that your differing typing style might make you more prone to repetitive stress injuries such as carpal tunnel.  If you start having pain problems, consider trying to learn to type more traditionally and it might help.

I probably only make around 60 WPM myself (depends what you consider a "word" -- insert two-byte joke here) so I don't think your speed is anything to worry about.

Comment: It's complete sentences with punctuation and capitals.  I've been typing constantly for over 10 years this way so I don't think carpel tunnel will be a problem, as I would have mild effects by now.

And yes, it seems to be the case that homerow/dvorak is less stress-prone.

Comment: You've been typing with two fingers since you were 8 years old?  What are you, some kind of savant? :)